# Build failure in a simple Maven project with wildfly (wildfly:deploy)

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, build, wildfly

Hi evryone im new in dev JavaEE i wanna to create an app web and i have created my BD and the ejb part with packages persistence, interfaces and services and in the war part i have created the package beans and the webapp .....
i do a

```
 clean install
```

in the ejb with build maven and when i go to the war part and i do

```
 wildfly:deploy
```

i got this big failure :(

```
mars 02, 2016 3:03:09 PM org.xnio.Xnio    clinit
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.2.Final
mars 02, 2016 3:03:10 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio clinit
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.2.Final
mars 02, 2016 3:03:10 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl clinit
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.3.Final


`[INFO]` BUILD FAILURE

`[INFO]` Total time: 10.396 s
`[INFO]` Finished at: 2016-03-02T15:03:15+02:00
`[INFO]` Final Memory: 15M/195M


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project pfeweb: Could not execute goal deploy on C:\Users\Amine_Info\workspace\pfeweb\target\pfeweb.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
`[ERROR]` "operation" => "read-attribute",
`[ERROR]` "address" => [],
`[ERROR]` "name" => "launch-type"
`[ERROR]` }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9991. The connection timed out
```

please i need help it has been 4 days looking for solution and i didnt found any thing to help 
thanks all

Comment: *Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9991* is pretty clear no?

Comment: But when i tape this address  i see the WILDFLY interface and even i can create a datasource ...

Comment: And when i try to do a full publish in the server WILDFLY of the "pfeweb.war" it didnt run and i got this problem :
INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "pfeweb.war"
      service jboss.deployment.unit."pfeweb.war".INSTALL

Comment: You're probably missing the `wildfly:start` in your *pom.xml*.

Comment: i already start Wildfly manually

Comment: i fixed the problem of connection but it steel the problem of the goal:
 Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project pfeweb: Deployment failed and was rolled back

Comment: Your pom.xml specifies port 19991 - not 9991.

Comment: no thats the right port and the connection work good but the goal of deploy cant be executed :/

Comment: if you get "deployment failed as was rolled back" it tells you that it could not successfully deploy your application, probably to some issue with application or its configuration. take a look at server.log / console of Wildfly where you will see full log of what went wrong.

Comment: i cant found a solution even i have creating another project and always the same problem :/
Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "medweb.war"

Comment: i even know changed to wildfly 10.0 and always the same problem

Answer (score 0):

this is my pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>tn.orange.pfe</groupId>
<artifactId>pfeweb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tn.orange.pfe</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <artifactId>pfeejb</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                <port>19991</port>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>wildflyadmin</password>

                <filename>${project.artifactId}.war</filename>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be two situations:
1.-Your wildfly server is not running so when wildfly plugin is trying to deploy it , it cannot authenticate through 127.0.0.1:9991

2.- Or the wildfly server is running, but you did not specify the ip or port properly. In order to do this, you have to properly set them in your pom.xml file and settings.xml. For further details see this [post](http://lauraliparulo.altervista.org/jboss-wildfly-maven-plugin-to-deploy-on-localhostremote-server/)